# SharePoint 2010 and Editform.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In one of my custom application user wants to keep EditForm.aspx open once list item is created and he can keep saving the same record without redirecting user to DisplayForm.aspx page.So what I'm doing after list item creation I'm loading EditForm.aspx again.

Now the problem is when form is opened in Edit mode and if existing field is modified that doesn't gets updated in the list item but if something new added to the field then it gets saved to the list. I believe it's postback issue but not sure how to pass latest form data upon save.

Answer (score 1):

If this was my task, I would create a new application page that replaces the edit page on that list.

(You can use powershell / object model to set the url of the new / edit / display pages)

Ignoring the ribbon, the edit page is actually pretty simple.  It shouldn't be too difficult to create a custom one, that has the submittal behavior you are interested in.  Indeed, since you are keeping the exact same field names and input types, you may be able to simply inherit the default form in yours, and simply override the post call.

I suppose it might be possible instead for you to write some javascript to hijack the submit post of the default edit page, but this seems messy to me, and I probably wouldn't go that route.

If you don't need to complete this task today, I've been meaning to push to github some code I wrote a few months ago.  That code is a custom aspx edit/new/display page that is extremely easy to customize / implement.  I could forward you the link tonight when I get out of work.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Please fwd me and I will see. btw I have customized editform.aspx but my app brings data from multiple list to display on Editform.aspx.

Comment: @Rishi I just got this message, will put it up tonight.